# Join a column on a specific position (after a specific column)

Tags: mysql

For example SELECT a.*,b.3 FROM a JOIN b

and i want the get the b.3 for example between a.5 and a.6

Is it possible? Or should i solve it on the php-side?

Comment: Your application should not care in what position columns in the result set are returned. You can fetch the values by column name.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. However using a.* is discouraged in production systems. You should list every field individually. I realize this can be a pain if there are too many fields. However this way you can get any order you want.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to list the fields in `a` specifically, i.e. one at a time, and not `a.*`. Then you can put `b.3` wherever you want.

You can also retrieve the data from the fields by name instead of by position in PHP, then you don't care about the order.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're asking for?

```
SELECT a.1, a.2, a.3, a.4, a.5, b.3, a.6, ...
    FROM a
        INNER JOIN b ...
```

Comment: @user877167: I'm sorry, but this is what you'd need to do to produce the results you desire.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way:

```
SELECT a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, b3, a6, a7 FROM a JOIN b
```